# AWS Node SDK Doesn't Have HttpClient

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-sdk

I am attempting to follow the AWS documentation for using the Node SDK to perform a signed HTTP request to Elasticsearch (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html#es-request-signing-node).

In the example, they use a class Aws.HttpClient to actually execute the request. But I have installed `aws-sdk` version 2.517.0 and HttpClient is not exposed by the `aws-sdk` object I import. My TypeScript autocompletion only indicates HttpRequest and HttpResponse and I can't compile if I use Aws.HttpClient.

But if I dig into node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http.js I can see AWS.HttpClient.

What do I have to do to access it? Or is the documentation outdated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this old issue:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1278

You can always add `// @ts-ignore` above relevant lines, or even create a `index.d.ts` file with type definitions.

Comment: Using ts-ignore worked! Thanks. I wish they would make type definitions though, as they use HttpClient as an example in their official documentation.